# Java 8 flatmap unwrap multiple objects from collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Looking to use some streams in a project and replace some of the logic currently implemented. Not sure if this type of case is a good use case for java stream api. Lets say we have a collection and we want to iterate through it and check values from two objects within the collection, and only if both of them are true will we return a populated optional.

```
 return Arrays.stream(someMultiDimensionalArray).flatMap(objectArray -> 
                    .filter(MyClass.class::isInstance)
                    .filter(v -> v.value().equals(true))
                    //need to do something here to do, && (if another value in the collection is true also)
                    .findFirst();
```

/

```
boolean one = false;
for(int i=0; i<objectArray.length; i++){
  if(!one && objectArray[i].hidden==true)
     one = true;

  if(objectArray[i].hidden == true && one)
   return objectArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Another value in the entire collection? What if there are multiple pairs of objects that match the condition?

Comment: If there are two objects which have a true field in the collection then the condition is met

Comment: What's it supposed to return?  I have no idea what a populated optional is.  You want to return the pair that are equal?

Comment: Maybe that updated code will clarify, if not maybe the logic is not sound.

Comment: @user2524908 That second if statement doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Your question implies a double for loop.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Also, `== true` is redundant and should be avoided.

Comment: I guess you have a `continue;` after `one=true;` ?

Comment: The conditions you wrote seem to just return the first found object where `hidden == true`. Why? at the beginning `one==false`, you set it to `true` if `hidden` is `true` and so the second condition is immediately `true` and you just return that value... So: do you want the first matching value? Or do you want the second matching value, if any? Do you want an empty optional, if there is only one match? Please clarify...

Comment: Every time a developer writes `condition == true`, a kitten gets killed. Just write `condition`, just like you have written `!one` and `one` instead of `one==false` and `one==true`…

Answer (score 3):

So, what you want is, if there are more than 1 objecst in the array that is having `hidden == true`, you want the 2nd one? (From what your code means).

So it is simply something like `stream.filter(o -> o.hidden).skip(1).findFirst()`

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned in comment above:

> If there are two objects which have a true field in the collection then the condition is met.

your if statements code snippet in loop can be merged as:

```
boolean one = false;
for(int i=0; i<objectArray.length; i++){
    if(!one && objectArray[i].hidden) {
        one = true;
        return objectArray[i];
    }
}
```

Indeed, It can be simplified as further:

```
for(int i=0; i<objectArray.length; i++){
    if(objectArray[i].hidden) {
        return objectArray[i];
    }
}
```

Then using for-each loop like this:

```
for(??? it: objectArray){
    if(it.hidden) {
        return it;
    }
}
```

**AND** then using stream-api like this:

```
return Arrays.stream(objectArray).filter(it->it.hidden).findFirst();
```

**maybe** you need cast instance & return a stream in `flatMap` in the first approach:

```
return Arrays.stream(someMultiDimensionalArray).flatMap(objectArray ->
        Arrays.stream(objectArray).filter(it->it.hidden).findFirst()
                                  .map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty())
)
.filter(MyClass.class::isInstance)
.map(MyClass.class::cast)
.filter(MyClass::value)
.findFirst();
```